# Android WebView don't show the content of the website

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I'm a noob in programming and I'm doing a WebView from a tracking website. The problem is, when I type the tracking code in the WebView the site doesn't show anything, I will show to you in next images:

- [Showed in the webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShSBm.png)
- [What should be showed in the webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmIM9.png)

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webview;
private static final String TAG = "Main";
private ProgressDialog progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "android");
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "WebView Example", "Loading...");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading url: " +url);
            if (progressBar.isShowing()){
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(description);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl("https://geartrack.hdn.pt");
}
public class WebAppInterface{
    Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.action_refresh:
            webview.loadUrl("https://geartrack.hdn.pt");
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()){
        webview.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is you haven't enabled [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for your WebView. If you use Chrome to [inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3) your WebView via developer tools, you will notice that you have an error. Specifically `main.js?v=1:373 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

**Why is this?** If you look at that line of code in `main.js` you will see that the script is accessing length of `localStorage`. It will crash the script because you can not access a property of an undefined variable. `localStorage` is undefined in a WebView by default, because `DomStorage` is not enabled.

To **fix** this. Enable LocalStorage for your WebView add the line:

`settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

Where `settings` is the `WebView`'s `WebSettings` object.

After doing this everything works as you should expect!